# Get Formik Validation Current Year and Up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik, yup

I need to get the validation using Formik that input should only be currentYear and up.

```
 const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

expiryYear: yup
.string()
.required('Select expiry year')
.min(4, `Invalid year format (Example: ${currentYear + 4})`)
.max(4, `Invalid year format (Example: ${currentYear + 4})`)
.when('startDate', (currentYear, schema) => currentYear && schema.min(currentYear)),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please:

```js
yup.date()
 .min(new Date().getFullYear(),
 'Year must be current year or greater than current year');
```

Check [the demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/shahnawazhossan-yup-year-6u20t)

If you would like to validate the year's length, you can use this:

```js
yup.number()
.test('len', 'Must be exactly 4 characters', 
val => val && val.toString().length === 4 ).min(new Date().getFullYear());
```

**This will validate the length of the year first, then check whether it is greater than or equal to current year.**

Comment: Thanks for this. However when i type `20`, it outputs expiryYear must be a `date` type, but the final value was: `Invalid Date` (cast from the value `"20"`). Where did this error messagecome from?  Can you add an additonal validator for this? Thanks. I'm using `type="text"` by the way

Comment: In which form you would like to take input? Please share your code, I think I can fix it out.  Would you like to validate whether your given year is having 4 digits or not as well?

Comment: Hi! Yes pls add that validation also.. Pls check this https://codesandbox.io/s/credit-card-dialog-react-material-formik-knges?file=/demo.js.

Comment: Hi, please firstly change your `textfield` from `text` to `number` and follow the above code I've added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also fix the month. I think its fixed already. But i have a problem, when i type `2`, it invalidates, it should be `02`. Is there a way that if i write `2`, it would automatically converts to `02`? Thanks

Comment: Brother, you've told it in your validator that in which format month should be written. If you write 2 there needs to do something extra, like you want to insert 0 at the left or right. It will be more complex as well.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I did it:

```
import yup from 'yup';
```

// useState Declaration and Definition area

```
  const [year, setYear]= React.useState('');
let [yearError, setYearError]= React.useState(false)
 
//Validating year for being a number, not null and not beyong current year

  const YearValidator= yup.number().test(val => val !== '' && val.toString().length 
  === 4 ).max(new Date().getFullYear()).required();
```

//now passing here year value (entered by user) for validation

```
   const validYear = YearValidator.isValidSync(year);
```

//showing error if validYear is not true..

```
yearError = validYear ? " year submitted" : "year is not valid";
    console.log(yearError);
    setYearError(yearError);
```

Now create a handleYearChange() function that takes the event change as argument like this...

```
const handleYearChange = (event)=>{
    setYear(event.target.value);
  }
```

Now call this function from your HTML tag where user enters the YEAR value

```
<div>
   <p className=""> Year of PassOut* </p>
      <input type="number" onChange={handlePassoutYearChange}/>
       <span> {yearError}</span>
  </div>
```